# Authentication & Authorization not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, authentication

I am first time dealing with authentication and authorization.

In my web.config i have following code for authentication & authorization:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="Authentication.aspx" timeout="30" defaultUrl="Default.aspx" cookieless="AutoDetect" >
        <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
            <user name="shiv" password="abc@123"/>
            <user name="raj" password="abc@123"/>
        </credentials>


    </forms>

</authentication>
  <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
  </authorization>
```

And

```
<location path="Admin.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="shiv"/>
                <deny users="*"/>

            </authorization>
        </system.web>

    </location>


    <location path="users.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="shiv"/>
                <allow users="raj"/>
                <deny users="*"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>

    </location>
```

**.cs Code:**

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(txtUserName.Text,txtPassword.Text))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtUserName.Text,true);
            }
        }
```

As my expectation,when i make login from 'raj' user, it should redirect me to `users.aspx` , but every time its redirecting me to `Default.aspx`

Why is this working so?

Has i made anything wrong?

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your web.config, in the `authentication/forms` section, change the `defaultUrl` appropriately:

change

```
defaultUrl="Default.aspx"
```

to this:

```
defaultUrl="users.aspx"
```

about **FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage**

```
Redirects an authenticated user back to the originally requested URL 
or the default URL.
```

Comment: but in location path for users.aspx i have written names of both raj nad shiv. It should go to that link. Isnt it?

Comment: location is not meant for that. location specifies whether a given section of the domain can be viewed by all or some or nobody in the authenticated users list